# What is a black, preserved egg called?

Tags: eggs

I remember some eggs which the egg yolk is solid and black, but forgot the source(seems like preserved), what is it?(if any)

Comment: Probably spoiled?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current most common term in English appears to be "century egg", but it's also been known as a thousand-year egg or hundred-year egg.

It's typically produced by aging in a solution of table salt, calcium hydroxide, and sodium carbonate, but traditional methods involved less refined versions of those chemicals wrapped in clay (and some quantity of rice bran).

More details in this [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_egg).

[image: Century egg]

Image: Wikipedia/Wiki commons

Comment: Is this that Asian egg that is fermented in urine?

Comment: @Davor, this is the same egg. Except it was never produced using urine. It's a common misconception due to the fact that it smells like ammonia which is commonly associated with urine. It is traditionally made using ash as the agent that lowers its pH. Century egg needs a pH of 9-12 while urine can only raise it to about 7.5-7.9.

Comment: Hence the dark, ashy color.

Comment: @Jay - I think that the fact that it's called "horse urine egg" in Thai has more to do with the misconception than the colour...

Comment: @Davor You might be thinking of Virgin Boy Eggs https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_boy_egg